# Spring Data JPA - Syntax error in native query for LPAD function

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am getting syntax error when trying to execute a native query in spring data jpa for lpad function to get the sequence as text

```
    @Query(value = "select lpad(nextval('finance_accounts_id_seq')::text, 8, '0')", nativeQuery = true)
    public String getNextValForSequence();
```

Hibernate:
select
lpad(nextval('finance_accounts_id_seq'):text,
8,
'0')
2022-01-30 09:10:21.102  WARN 16108 --- [nio-8082-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42601
2022-01-30 09:10:21.102 ERROR 16108 --- [nio-8082-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: syntax error at or near ":"

I am currently using postgres with Spring Data JPA.

Comment: If you use native syntax that query should work in any SQL client for your database. Does it work?

Comment: Yes it works in sql client

Comment: No idea then, seems to be a parsing problem in the JPA side then but it should not be doing anything but passing it to the DB

Answer (score 1):

The following query worked for me in Spring Data JPA

```
@Query(value = "select to_char(nextval('finance_business_accounts_pan_seq'), 'fm00000000')", nativeQuery = true)
```